# How to write a SWIG file to make C function call Java targeted language

Tags: java, c, swig

To simply my question, I have 2 C functions declared in header file, these functions acts as interfaces which will be called by C library. The function  implementation needs to use Java languages.

The functions or interface are declared as followings:

```
example.h

extern void Receive(uint_8* payload, int length);
extern int Send(uint8_t* payload, int length);
```

My questions are what is the best way to define java interface and how to write a swig file in order for C library to call back Java implementation?

Any idea would be appreciated.

Comment: You're asking for a tutorial.  Surely you can find several with a Web search.

Comment: you are asking for _directors_, there are samples in documentation http://www.swig.org/Doc3.0/Java.html#Java_directors

Comment: Thanks for your help ! From the document, "new classes called directors are introduced at the bottom of the C++ inheritance chain." It seems there is only way to write C++ class and wrap c functions,so that SWIG could generate java interface and make c function call to java object.